# Showing JQuery selection depending on selection

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page on my website that will show / hide fields on a form depending on what

**HTML/PHP Code:**

```
<select name="task_to_do" id="task_to_do" class="form-control" required>
    <option value="0">--- CHOOSE A TASK ---</option>
    <option value="1"<?= $task['task_to_do'] == "1" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>-> task 1</option>
    <option value="2"<?= $task['task_to_do'] == "2" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>-> task 2</option>
    <option value="3"<?= $task['task_to_do'] == "3" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>-> task 3</option>                           
    <option value="4"<?= $task['task_to_do'] == "4" ? " selected" : ""; ?>>-> task 4</option>
</select>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
$('#task_to_do').on('change',function() {

    // show public sites ...
    if (this.value == '1') {
        $("#register_public").show();
    } else {
        $("#register_public").hide();
    }

    // show private sites ...
    if (this.value == '2') {
        $("#register_private").show();
    } else {
        $("#register_private").hide();
    }

    // show login & post ...
    if (this.value == '3') {
        $("#post").show();
    } else {
        $("#post").hide();
    }

    // show email ...
    if (this.value == '4') {
        $("#email").show();
    } else {
        $("#email").hide();
    }

});
</script>
```

This works well when the task is being created, the issue i have is when the task is being edited, i will allow the user to see their tasks and hit the edit button, when clicked, the user will see the form populated and what should happen is, depending on what **task_to_do** is selected, the jquery will show the relevant section, as it is now the user needs to re-select the section again before it shows, but it should be automatically shown on the page load, i'm not 100% with JQuery, any tips / or help would be appreciated.